# vxworks, at runtime determine debug mode

Tags: c++, c, tornado, vxworks

I'm using Tornado 2.2 for vxworks and in my application I would like to use a section of code if in debug else another section for runtime. Is there a way to determine if I have compiled in debug vs release at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: In most development environments, mode does not change during run-time between release and debug.

Comment: I didn't say it changed at runtime I am saying how to tell if the build is debug or release at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a global variable:

```
#if defined(NDEBUG) // Or whatever your compiler uses
const bool compiled_as_debug = true;
#else
const bool compiled_as_debug = false;
#endif
```

Look up your compiler documentation for predefined macros or identifiers and see if there are better ones for determining debug mode.

Comment: I've looked in the documentation and on the internet that is why I am asking the question here. I can't find a specific DEBUG macro and of course NDEBUG does not work in VXWORKS, well at least my version of Tornado 2.2